# Socket.io events are being broadcasted and emitted but I'm not getting the intended output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, fabricjs

I have a canvas (fabric.js) where in userA and userB can login and work together while sharing real time updates on both of their screens. According to my backend script's log statements the events are being broadcast. The log statements appear in the terminal but the drawings of userA are not visible on the screen of userB and vice versa.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.user.username} with ID ${socket.user.id} is connected`);

    socket.on('draw:start', ({ x, y }) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('draw:start', {x, y});
        console.log("draw:start event broadcasted")
    });
    
    socket.on('draw:progress', ({ x, y }) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('draw:progress', { x, y });
        console.log("draw:progress event broadcasted")

    });

    socket.on('draw:end', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('draw:end');
        console.log("draw:end event broadcasted")

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`User ${socket.user.username} with ID ${socket.user.id} disconnected`);
    });
});
```

The front end part

```
useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);
        fabricCanvasRef.current = fabricCanvas;

        fabricCanvas.isDrawingMode =true;
        fabricCanvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
        fabricCanvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'black';

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log("Token from frontend side ", token);

        socketRef.current = io('http://localhost:8080', {
            query: {
                token: token
            }
        });
        
        fabricCanvas.on('mouse:down', (event) => {
            const { x, y } = event.pointer;
            console.log(`Mouse down - X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`);
            socketRef.current.emit('draw:start', { x, y });
        });

        fabricCanvas.on('mouse:move', (event) => {
            if (!fabricCanvasRef.current.isDrawingMode) return;
            const { x, y } = event.pointer;
            console.log(`Mouse move - X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`);
            socketRef.current.emit('draw:progress', { x, y });
        });

        fabricCanvas.on('mouse:up', () => socketRef.current.emit('draw:end'));

        return () => {
            fabricCanvas.off('mouse:down', (event) => {
                const { x, y } = event.pointer;
                console.log(`Mouse down - X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`);
                socketRef.current.emit('draw:start', { x, y });
            });

            fabricCanvas.off('mouse:move', (event) => {
                if (!fabricCanvasRef.current.isDrawingMode) return;
                const { x, y } = event.pointer;
                console.log(`Mouse move - X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`);
                socketRef.current.emit('draw:progress', { x, y });
            });

            fabricCanvas.off('mouse:up', () => socketRef.current.emit('draw:end'));
            socketRef.current.disconnect();
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: You are emitting `draw:start` event inside of `draw:start` event listener  in server code which will cause recursion. Rename it to  `socket.broadcast.emit('paint:start',...)`.

Comment: in client size I don't see any event listener callbacks that perform draw on canvas so what are you expecting ??

Comment: @bogdanoff Previously I had those as seperate functions and then I would pass it to fabricCanvas.on as events but then I won't get the log statements in frontend. I tried inline event binding this seem to work. However, it also logs out co-ordinates of my free mouse movements when I don't hold the click

Comment: it should be `socketRef.current.on( '...' , ... )` not  `fabricCanvas.on( '...' , ... )`

Comment: @bogdanoff I don't get the log statements of co-ordinates now after doing the above changes and neither an error